# Unable to Scroll Elements inside ListView with Appium Selenium Android

Tags: selenium, listview, appium, horizontalscrollview

For a few days I try to find a simple solution for scroll inside a list view

Since that Appium Inspector not provide the all elements of the list (only by manualy swipe and refresh the inspector then the new elements with the new instance loads.

After research i find out the distance between list item is as follow:

```
Item Location= (15, 828)
Item Location= (15, 1209)
Item Location= (15, 1590)
```

So i guess that every click need to scroll 381 pixels down, after so many tries I cannot find solution for this part of code and will be happy if someone can help with that:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.id("net.balink.diplomat.qa:id/btnAddToCart"));
System.out.println("List Size is= " + list.size());

for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
    WebElement listItem = list.get(j);
    Point location = listItem.getLocation();
    System.out.println("Location= " + location);
    listItem.click();

    //to do here: swipe 381 px down after any click, then re-initialize 
    //the listItem in order to get a new index - and the loop when 
    //theres no more list items

    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using the following method for scrolling screen:

```
public static MobileElement scrollElementByContentDesc(String scrollableList, String uiSelector, String textToSearchInList) {
        return driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
                "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"" + scrollableList + "\")).getChildByDescription("
                        + "new UiSelector().className(\"" + uiSelector + "\"), \"" + textToSearchInList+ "\")"));

    }
```

**scrollableList** is id of your scrollable List element,

**uiSelector** is the className of the item of list,

**textToSearchInList** can be any text that you need to search in the list. It can be any random text if your purpose is just to scroll till the end of the list.

Call this method from any method:

```
public void someMethod(){
//other code
try{
    MobileElement element= scrollElementByContentDesc("your scrollableList id",
                "uiSelector classname", "any text you need to find in the list);
}catch(Exception e){
    //do nothing
}
}
```

If you want to swipe by co0rdinate, you can do like this.

```
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.touch.WaitOptions;
import io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.PointOption;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static java.time.Duration.ofSeconds;

TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver); 
action.press(PointOption.point(115, 650)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(ofSeconds(1)))
                .moveTo(PointOption.point(115, 350)).release().perform();
```

> Make sure to import correct library.

Comment: thanks Suban but it still throw me exception any time call to :

Comment: what kinds of exception is it throwing?

Comment: never mind the exception always occur although the scroll function well,

the thing is that the solution that "dmle" provide indeed perform scroll but not always to the exact location,

actually I'm looking for Swipe option that can always swipe exact distance



when I record by Appium inspector this code generated:

    (new TouchAction(driver))
      .press({x: 529, y: 593})
      .moveTo({x: 523: y: 1725})
      .release()
      .perform()

but Appium still not recognize the ".press" as a function

I'll really appreciate if you find provide me swipe function by distance!

Comment: This link may be helpful for you. [Link](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/)

Comment: I try with the follow code:
    TouchAction act = new TouchAction(driver);
    act.press(529,593).moveTo(523,1725).perform();

but still the "act.press()"

the .press have problem: "The method press(PointOption) in the type TouchAction is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)"

Comment: you need to use **act.press(PointOption.point(529, 593))** not act.press(529,593)

Comment: Thank you so much Suban!
indeed seems that code you suggested looks good,
I've wrote the follow code:
TouchAction act = new TouchAction(driver);
  act.press(PointOption.point(529, 593)).moveTo(PointOption.point(529, 1725)).perform();

indeed it's not throwing exception but it's do not perform swipe
actually, I need to scroll down from point 529,593 to point 529, 1725
how do I perform swipe with your suggestion?

Comment: **act.press(PointOption.point(529, 593)).moveTo(PointOption.point(529, 1725)).release().perform();** this should work. you forget to put **release()** in your code.

Comment: Thanks Suban!
I really appreciate your help!
Now it pretty works I'm so happy finally find the solution thanks to your great knowledge! 

wish you all the best!!!

Answer (score 3):

The more reliable approach is to use native UiAutomator way:

So first of all find parent view of your list elements with `scrollable: true` attribute in place. That definitely should be at least one.

Then use inspector to build & test your `UiAutomator` locator

```
MobileElement elementScrollTo = driver
            .findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()"
            + ".resourceId(\"android:id/list\")).scrollIntoView("
            + "new UiSelector().text(\"Some text\"));");
```

`UiSelector` has pretty rich [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector) , check it and find what suits you best.

This approach is better than TouchActions as you are not dependent on device screen resolution/coordinates.